Why are the outside of the rings of an afterburner exhaust brighter that the rest?
In this answer’s comments, it is explained (with a link for more information) why afterburners have rings in the exhaust.
To summarize, the rumble of the engine + afterburner creates a resonance that causes density changes throughout the exhaust.
However I can’t seem to understand why the outer part of these discs are brighter.

If you zoom in, it’s clear that there are these ring structures in the exhaust. My question is why is the outer part of these discs brighter (AKA higher density)? Shouldn’t the pulses be equal throughout each disc? (It looks more equal when you look at the ones closer to the nozzle)
The document linked in that answer goes over the different frequencies that cause this effect, but I couldn’t seem to find anything on why the outer part of the disc is brighter.

The best theory I have so far is that the outer flow of the exhaust has more unburnt fuel, but I wouldn’t know why that would be the case.

It also seems that the outer part is (close to) the same brightness as the inner part on the rings closer to the nozzle.

The air pressure causes the exhaust to collapse in until it gets too compressed and air pressure isn't strong enough anymore to squeeze it. It's still hot and energetic, so it rebounds back out until it's equal to the air pressure. At that point, the air pressure starts squeezing back in again, causing the exhaust to collapse again, and so on. The bright points in the exhaust cone are the spots where the exhaust is squeezed in due to atmospheric pressure.

@AadirajAnil It sounds like you’re describing Mach diamonds. The last few comments of the first linked answer should clear things up.

“I have to guess, but the jet looks like it has almost atmospheric pressure and the rings are the consequence of density changes resulting from oscillations ("afterburner rumble") in the afterburner pipe. So they are not actually shock diamonds.” - One of the comments on the linked answers talking about this same effect.

I'm guessing it's the same phenomenon responsible for smoke rings.

@MichaelHall Good point. It seems that this subject isn’t documented very much from what I’ve researched.

When you say "outer part of the ring" do you mean the existence of the rings themselves?  i.e. Why not a flat glowing disc with each pulse, why do they manifest as a ring?

@MichaelHall I made an edit changing just that. (I think it sounds right, but if not let me know!)

OK, I don't know enough about mach diamonds to merge the info into a good and complete answer, but for more information to back my hunch above, they would seem to be a vortex ring:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_ring

The brightness in the diamonds/rings is not due to external combustion in the flow. The light comes out of the afterburner and is refracted by the external flow. The angle of refraction varies with gas pressure (influencing the refraction index). This reveals where the shock disks are located. The flow itself produces no light.

@mins That sounds very plausible. I had not thought of that before, and that would explain why only the outer part of the discs are super bright.

I'm not sure this explanation is complete thou, it's possible carbon particles and/or water droplets are also glowing due to pressure and temperature as explained here (simple black-body radiation without combustion). Also be aware of IR being captured as white by many sensors. This Q/A on space.se about cryogenic plumes (not colored) seems to confirm both effects.
